# Google's Speech Recognition API Usage Limits

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm using speech recognition api of Google. I created a wrapper in Java (like this: http://pastebin.com/zJEhnJ74); all works quite fine but sometimes I receive http 403 or http 500 so I'm thinking that there are some day limits.

I know that this is not an official API but someone knows the limit of the service (max requests for day, max length of audio file, and so on)?

Comment: Looks like there is a quota indeed

Comment: Yes, infact. I think so

Answer (score 6):

There is a maximum time limit for an individual Speech Recognition 'session' which seems to be around 60 seconds. That means that you can have Google process a sentence but then you need to end that session and start a new one.

If you can use JavaScript then you should use the SpeechRecognition API - take a look at a simple example that I wrote in [this tutorial](http://apprentice.craic.com/tutorials/37)

Answer (score 2):

There are limits besides the amount of time for a single request. I finally hit a limit recently after a lot of experimentation; as soon as a request starts, it's cut short.
On a desktop web browser (Chrome), there's [a limit for each user](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/lCVh_kqxohg) (Primiano Tucci works at Google, so I'd trust him!), and [you can't buy more time with the API](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys).

However, as you could see from the first link, the exception appears to be Chrome on Android, which apparently has no limitations because it accesses an internal API for speech recognition when visiting web pages that use the Web Speech API.

For desktop browsers, you're out of luck unless you can assume users don't mind a limit. Even Annyang and voice dictation in Google Docs aren't working for me at the moment, while online voice recognition services that don't go through Google are working.