# Google Speech API streaming audio exceeding 1 minute

Tags: audio, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I would like to be able to extract utternaces of a person from a stream of telephone audio. The phone audio is routed to my server which then creates a streaming recognition request. How can I tell when a word exists as part of a complete utterance or is part of an utterance currently being transcribed? Should I compare timestamps between words? Will the API continue to return interim results even if there is no speech for a certain amount of time in the streaming phone audio? How can I exceed the 1-minute of streaming audio limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first 3 questions:

You don’t need to compare timestamps between words, you can tell if a word is part of a complete utterance (final result) by looking at the `is_final flag` in the [Streaming Recognition Result](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#streamingrecognitionresult). If the flag is set to true, the response corresponds to a completed transcription, otherwise, it is an interim result. More on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#google.cloud.speech.v1.StreamingRecognizeResponse).

Once you get the final results, no interim results should be generated until new utterances are streamed.

Regarding your last question, you can’t exceed the 1 minute limit, you need to send [multiple requests](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#streaming-requests) instead.